# Equivalent of bash !! that ignores first word

Tags: bash, productivity

In bash, I frequently do

```
touch whatever.py
vim whatever.py
```

I want something like

```
touch whatever.py
vim !!
```

So how do I do that with a bash ! directive that eats the first word?

Comment: You don't need to use `touch` since vim will create the file if it doesn't exist (after you :w of course).

Comment: You're right, bad example. In real life I am actually doing "touchmod", which is a personal alias that touches and then chmods u+x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!*` will give you the everything in the previous command except the command itself.

`!$` will give you the last parameter for the previous command.

Both should work in your example (a command with a single parameter).